# concurrency with asynchronous for loop in python

Tags: python, mongodb, async-await, concurrency

Let's say I have three different collections of bunch of lists from mongodb database. Every list contains *amount* field. I need measured amount or balance from all items. What is the best way to do concurrency in python? For a large data set is there any chance to remain breach of calculation while using async await feature as I expect the exact measurement?

```
async def get_balance():
  balance = 0
  for item in await collection1.find().to_list(100000):
      balance += item["amount"]
  for item in await collection2.find().to_list(100000):
      balance *= item["amount"]
  for item in await collection3.find().to_list(100000):
      balance -= item["amount"]
  return balance
```

Comment: you're not taking advantage of async here because all the heavy I/O work related to `find` is still inside synchronous `for` loops. you would need three coroutines and a synchronization primitive so that each coroutine can only access `balance` one at a time as to not create race conditions

Comment: _async_ just before _for_ does that ?

Comment: how to do it? @gold_cy